# What is the purpose of 'Output properties' in Angular2 directives?

Tags: angular

Today I started learning Angular2 and I can clearly see why 'Input properties' in directive is needed because it makes parent -> child communication much easier but I don't completely understand use case of 'Output properties' in directives. Could anyone explain it?

[Link to official docs.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs)

Comment: It facilitates communication in the other direction: child -> parent.  See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs if you haven't read these parts of the docs yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the way to implement custom events in Angular2. A child component can trigger an event the parent can subscribe on.

Imagine the child component can trigger the `someEvent` event. You can use the following syntax (`(event-name)="..."`) to call the `doSomething` method when the event occurs:

```
<child (someEvent)="doSomething($event)"></child>
```

`$event` contains the value that is provided when triggers the event. Imy sample `$event` corresponds to `'some value'`.

The child component simply needs to define an output for this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    (...)
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output()
  someEvent:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  emitCustomEvent() {
    this.someEvent.emit('some value');
  }
}
```

The `emitEvent` method can be called within the child component on a click for example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div (click)="emitCustomEvent()">Emit custom event</div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  (...)
}
```